# JavascriptResult puts javascript to the page as a string?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Iam a newbie of .NET MVC. I was trying to run all return types of MVC but I couldnt do work javascriptResult. The below is in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult DoSomething() {
        string s = "alert('Hello world!');";
        return JavaScript(s);
    }
```

This is in my view

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("click", "DoSomething", new AjaxOptions())
```

When I clicked the link, it puts "alert('Hello world!');" as a string and so not firing the alert. Whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the documentation is "wrong" and the [`Controller.JavaScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.javascript%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) action result is most likely only considered to return JavaScript include files ([see also this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1716356.aspx/1)):

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult JavaScript()
{
    string s = "alert('Hello world!');";
    return JavaScript(s);
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Controller/JavaScript"></script>
```

If you want to return inline JavaScript you can use [`Controller.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.content%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as your action result in combination with [`Html.RenderAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult JavaScript()
{
    string s = "alert('Hello world!');";
    return Content(s);
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("JavaScript", "Controller"); }
</script>
```